# How to use an inner tag by class or id to drag and drop an entire element in pure js?

Tags: javascript

I have example of drag and drop: https://codepen.io/ilq-trifonow/pen/GRmaoBP

Now I can move elements by any part of them. But I want to use a `<p>` tag with a `class="drag-handler"` for this. How can I do it?

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Список задач с drag & drop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="tasks">
        <h1 class="tasks__title">To do list</h1>
        
        <div class="tasks__list">
          <div class="tasks__item"><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn HTML</p></div>
          <div class="tasks__item"><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn CSS</p></div>
          <div class="tasks__item"><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn JavaScript</p></div>
          <div class="tasks__item"><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn PHP</p></div>
          <div class="tasks__item"><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>stay alive</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const tasksListElement = document.querySelector(`.tasks__list`);
const taskElements = tasksListElement.querySelectorAll(`.tasks__item`);

for (const task of taskElements) {
  task.draggable = true;
}

tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragstart`, (evt) => {
  evt.target.classList.add(`selected`);
});

tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragend`, (evt) => {
  evt.target.classList.remove(`selected`);
});

const getNextElement = (cursorPosition, currentElement) => {
  const currentElementCoord = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const currentElementCenter = currentElementCoord.x + currentElementCoord.width / 2;
  
  const nextElement = (cursorPosition < currentElementCenter) ?
    currentElement :
    currentElement.nextElementSibling;
  
  return nextElement;
};

tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragover`, (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  const activeElement = tasksListElement.querySelector(`.selected`);
  const currentElement = evt.target;
  const isMoveable = activeElement !== currentElement &&
    currentElement.classList.contains(`tasks__item`);
    
  if (!isMoveable) {
    return;
  }
  
  const nextElement = getNextElement(evt.clientX, currentElement);
  
  if (
    nextElement && 
    activeElement === nextElement.previousElementSibling ||
    activeElement === nextElement
  ) {
    return;
  }
        
    tasksListElement.insertBefore(activeElement, nextElement);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `draggable=true` for all inner tag (say `p.drag-handler`) and then in `dragover` listener use `parentElement` as a `currentElement` that must be dragged.

Here is working sample:

```js
 const tasksListElement = document.querySelector(`.tasks__list`);
 const taskElements = tasksListElement.querySelectorAll(`.drag-handler`);

 for (const task of taskElements) {
     task.draggable = true;
 }

 tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragstart`, (evt) => {
     evt.target.parentElement.classList.add(`selected`);
 });

 tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragend`, (evt) => {
     evt.target.parentElement.classList.remove(`selected`);
 });

 const getNextElement = (cursorPosition, currentElement) => {
     const currentElementCoord = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
     const currentElementCenter = currentElementCoord.x + currentElementCoord.width / 2;

     const nextElement = (cursorPosition < currentElementCenter) ?
         currentElement :
         currentElement.nextElementSibling;

     return nextElement;
 };

 tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragover`, (evt) => {
     evt.preventDefault();

     const activeElement = tasksListElement.querySelector(`.selected`);
     const currentElement = evt.target.parentElement;
     const isMoveable = activeElement !== currentElement &&
         currentElement.classList.contains(`tasks__item`);

     if (!isMoveable) {
         return;
     }

     const nextElement = getNextElement(evt.clientX, currentElement);
     tasksListElement.insertBefore(activeElement, nextElement);
 });
```

```css
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 25px;
            color: #164a44;
            background-color: #b2d9d0;
        }

        .tasks__title {
            margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .tasks__list {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .tasks__item {
            width: 250px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px dashed #b2d9d0;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #dff2ef;
            transition: background-color 0.5s;
        }

            .tasks__item:last-child {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

        .selected {
            opacity: 0.6;
        }

    .drag-handler {
            background-color: #ddd;
            cursor: move;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="tasks">
        <h1 class="tasks__title">To do list</h1>
        <div class="tasks__list">
            <div class="tasks__item" ><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn HTML</p></div>
            <div class="tasks__item" ><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn CSS</p></div>
            <div class="tasks__item" ><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn JavaScript</p></div>
            <div class="tasks__item" ><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>learn PHP</p></div>
            <div class="tasks__item" ><p class="drag-handler">Drag it</p><p>stay alive</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to move the element by selecting inside of the paragraph element to move the entire containing div element.

In the scope of what you have written, I would simply use an implicit reference inside of the child node to set the draggable element when you select it

```js
for (const task of taskElements) {
  task.firstChild.addEventListener(`mousedown`, (evt) => {
    task.draggable = true
    task.classList.add(`selected`)
  })
}
```

Further to this, I wouldn't rely on DOM reads / writes as it tends to be more expensive than simply holding onto a reference to the element you are looking for:

```js
let activeElement

for (const task of taskElements) {
  task.firstChild.addEventListener(`mousedown`, (evt) => {
    task.draggable = true
    activeElement = task
  })
}

...

tasksListElement.addEventListener(`dragover`, (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  const currentElement = evt.target;
  const isMoveable = activeElement !== currentElement &&
    currentElement.classList.contains(`tasks__item`);
    
  if (!isMoveable) {
    return;
  }
  
  const nextElement = getNextElement(evt.clientX, currentElement);
  
  if (
    nextElement && 
    activeElement === nextElement.previousElementSibling ||
    activeElement === nextElement
  ) {
    return;
  }
        
    tasksListElement.insertBefore(activeElement, nextElement);
});
```

I gave this a try in your codepen, should be fine.